# Accessing information from Facebook using fql

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to use the Facebook SDK and fql to get the location information from a user's last status update or check in.

I have acquired an access token which passes the tests on their
[Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token) and states that the access token has the following scope:

```
create_note email photo_upload publish_actions publish_stream read_stream share_item status_update user_friends user_status video_upload
```

However when I use the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to debug the fql statement `SELECT coords FROM location_post WHERE author_uid = <USER_ID>` it returns the error:

```
{
     "error": {
     "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.", 
     "type": "OAuthException", 
     "code": 104
    }
}
```

Please help me figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the browser was in "private mode" which means the Facebook SDK could not get access to the $_SESSION. It worked once the browser was back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the issue with permissions, pl note that-

> To read Posts with location information, you need:
>
> user_photos or friends_photos for Photos
>
> user_status or friends_status for Posts (not including Photos)